# Having two form tags with two actions on single page

Tags: asp.net

I am having two form tags on single page and they both are redirected to different url.

```
 button = "<form id='frm1' action='https://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp' method=POST>" +
                        "<input type='image' src='../Images/btn_paynow.gif' border='0' name='submit'>" +
</form>

 button = "<form id='frm2' action='https://secure.payu.in/_payment' method=POST>" +
                            "<input type='image' src='../Images/btn_paynow.gif' border='0' name='submit'>" +
</form>
```

Please help me to handle it.
It is not at all redirecting to proper page. I tried code on: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664/Specifying-multiple-actions-from-a-single-Form but it is not working.

Comment: Your question is very unclear! please clarify what exactly is it you're trying to achieve/want?

Comment: How is the above code even related to the article you linked to? We can _infer_ what you are trying to do, but you have to specify/clarify your question. That article is from 2000, and if we infer your question to WebForms, then refer to [`Button.PostBackUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For MVC/WebPages/Razor, this would be moot.

Comment: There are two buttons, clicking on one button redirect to one url and clicking on another redirect to another url. I am generating button at run time with hidden fields. But as I declare two form tags it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link which I have posted in question solved my problem. It is worth vote 5.